# Geting the position of an array element in node js express

Tags: node.js

i have retrieved a list of abjects from firebase onto my ejs file: and i am retrieving them in this manner:

```
                                  <form id="eventform" method="post" action="/dasha">
                                    <%Object.keys(notes).forEach(function(key){%>
                                <tbody id="event" name="event">

                                    <tr>
                                       <td>1</td>

                                    <input type="hidden" id="categ" name="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">

                                    <td id="evname" name="evname"><%=notes[key].event %></td>
                                    </form>
                                    <td><%=notes[key].location %></td>
                                    <td><%=notes[key].codes %></td>
                                    <td><%=notes[key].date %></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <% }) %>

                                </tbody>
```

I am however trying to implement an Onclick for so that when an item is clicked on it carries its info to the next page: I have tried to store it in aninput field like:

```
**<input type="hidden" id="categ" name="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">**
```

But i just cant get the individual item it pulls the whole array when i check for the value.Any help
Here is the sample data[image]

[image]

Then i use jquery to submit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#event").click(function(){
    var en = $("#evname").val();
    $("#categ").val(en);
    $("#eventform").submit();
    });
});
```

Here is the rendered htmlsource and images /:

```
<tbody id="eventName" class="eventName" style="cursor: crosshair;" name="eventName">
                                          <%Object.keys(notes).forEach(function(key,idx){%>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td id="tid" name="tid" class="tid" ><%= idx %></td>

                                           <form name="eventForm-<%= idx %>" class="eventForm" method="post" action="/dasha">
                                <input type="hidden" id="categ-<%= idx %>" name="categ" class="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">
                                <input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" class="idd" value="<%= idx %>">
 </form>
                                <td id="evname-<%= idx %>"  name="evname-<%= idx %>"><%=notes[key].event %></td> 
                                            <td id="elocation" name="elocation"><%=notes[key].location %></td>
                                            <td id="ecodes" name="ecodes"><%=notes[key].code %></td>
                                            <td id="edate" name="edate"><%=notes[key].date %></td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <% }) %>

                                        </tbody>
```

[image]

Here is the rendered html from the browser:

```
<tbody id="eventName" class="eventName" style="cursor: crosshair;" name="eventName">

                                        <tr>
                                           <td id="tid" name="tid" class="tid">0</td>

                                       <form name="eventForm-0" class="eventForm" method="post" action="/dasha"></form>
                            <input type="hidden" id="categ-0" name="categ" class="categ" value="zuri.png">
                            <input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" class="idd" value="0">

                            <td id="evname-0" name="evname-0">zuri.png</td> 
                                        <td id="elocation" name="elocation">zuri.png</td>
                                        <td id="ecodes" name="ecodes"></td>
                                        <td id="edate" name="edate">-LZfAvzWGudUK78TGtT_</td>
                                        </tr>


                                        <tr>
                                           <td id="tid" name="tid" class="tid">1</td>

                                       <form name="eventForm-1" class="eventForm" method="post" action="/dasha"></form>
                            <input type="hidden" id="categ-1" name="categ" class="categ" value="Africa Tourism Technology and Innovation Awards">
                            <input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" class="idd" value="1">

                            <td id="evname-1" name="evname-1">Africa Tourism Technology and Innovation Awards</td> 
                                        <td id="elocation" name="elocation">USIU – Africa</td>
                                        <td id="ecodes" name="ecodes">AA24VI</td>
                                        <td id="edate" name="edate">25th – 26th April, 2019</td>
                                        </tr>


                                        <tr>
                                           <td id="tid" name="tid" class="tid">2</td>

                                       <form name="eventForm-2" class="eventForm" method="post" action="/dasha"></form>
                            <input type="hidden" id="categ-2" name="categ" class="categ" value="2nd Annual Global M I C E Summit">
                            <input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" class="idd" value="2">

                            <td id="evname-2" name="evname-2">2nd Annual Global M I C E Summit</td> 
                                        <td id="elocation" name="elocation">Trademark Hotel</td>
                                        <td id="ecodes" name="ecodes">RT79XV</td>
                                        <td id="edate" name="edate">11th – 13th September, 2019</td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your actual data please?

Comment: @TommyBs i have updated the Question with an image of my db

Comment: I was hoping for a representation of your `notes` object rather than the DB, because the first thing I can tell you is none of your key names such as `event`, `location` etc. match any columns in your db

Comment: @TommyBs i have re edited the question. and my aonly query is <input type="hidden" id="categ" name="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">** cannot hold a single value it takes the whole array.

Comment: Can you also add your onclick handler please? If you view the page source is it outputting all that info in the "value" field of the hidden input then? Or is it the handler that's getting the whole array

Comment: there is  a form inside the html <form><input type="hidden" id="categ" name="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">
 </form> I am trying to get the value of <%=notes[key].event %>, since it is a list in a table, so if i click the handler submits the form, but when i click on the  second element in table it doesnt pick.

Comment: In the html you've posted you close a `form` tag but never open it, and it's within your `forEach` loop so my guess is your html is invalid somewhere. Also the ID attribute should be unique, which it won't in your case as your hidden input has the same ID for every loop in the forEach. As such document.getElementById('categ') is most likely only returning the first instance it finds. Please post the full code of your html output and the onclick method where you try to retrieve the ID. Or show the code that handles the form submit. Or if it's javascript you use show us that onClick handler

Comment: ok. i edited the question.the submit query is included and the full html code where i retrieve the values in a form inside a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues with your code, and despite trying to highlight them in comments there isn't enough space, hence this 'incomplete' answer

For starters you are opening a `form` tag before your `forEach` loop. You then close it during the first loop. So on your subsequent iterations there isn't a form to find.

Secondly, you have reused the same ID during the loop, which you should not do as it will generate multiple items with the same ID if you have multiple Objects you're looping through. If you have 2 elements with an ID of 'foo', using multiple of the same ID will lead to unintended consequences , each ID should be unique.

Thirdly you don't have a `<table>` tag around your `tbody`, some browsers therefore strip the `tbody` so you're click event will never fire. Also your rows are within a `<tr>` element so you should attach your click handler to this.

```
                         <form id="eventform" method="post" action="/dasha">
                            <%Object.keys(notes).forEach(function(key){%>
                        <tbody id="event" name="event">

                            <tr>
                               <td>1</td>

                            <input type="hidden" id="categ" name="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">

                            <td id="evname" name="evname"><%=notes[key].event %></td>
                            </form> // YOU'RE CLOSING YOUR FORM HERE INSIDE THE LOOP ITERATION
                            <td><%=notes[key].location %></td>
                            <td><%=notes[key].codes %></td>
                            <td><%=notes[key].date %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% }) %>

                        </tbody>
```

Now this isn't tested, and as I don't know the complete layout of your page it's a bit of a stab in the dark, but you could try something like the following and see if you have any luck

```
                                <%Object.keys(notes).forEach(function(key,idx){%>
                           <table>
                            <tbody id="event-<%= idx =>" name="event" class="eventName">

                                <tr class="row">
                                   <td>1</td>
                                 <form name="eventForm-<%= idx %>" class="eventForm" method="post" action="/dasha">
                                <input type="hidden" id="categ-<%= idx %>" name="categ" class="categ" value="<%=notes[key].event %>">
 </form>
                                <td id="evname-<%= idx %>" name="evname-<%= idx %>"><%=notes[key].event %></td> 
                                <td><%=notes[key].location %></td>
                                <td><%=notes[key].codes %></td>
                                <td><%=notes[key].date %></td>
                                </tr>
                                <% }) %>

                            </tbody>
                           </table>
```

And a click handler similar to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".row").click(function(ev){
    let form = ev.currentTarget.querySelector('form');
    form.submit()
});
```

A simpler version using vanilla JS can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/xvag0mj2/

Comment: i have tried but now it takes the last value in the list. perhaps if you know a way we can access this <%= idx %> value on the handler script.

Comment: Can you post an example of the actual rendered html?

Comment: Sorry I meant the rendered source of the html, not a screenshot of it

Comment: That doesn't look like the rendered html as you've still got all the `<%= idx %>` code in there and the `<%Object.keys(notes).forEach(function(key,idx){%>`, Open the page and use inspect element or similar in your browser to get the actual rendered result html, not the code in your template file

Comment: i have posted it on the question

Comment: Ok, looking at your rendered HTML there's a couple of issues. Your `form` tags are closed before your hidden input elements, so your forms aren't submitting any data. Attach your click handler to the `<tr>` elements based on how your data is structured rather than the `<tbody>` as your `<tbody>` tag is wrapped around all the data fields. Just give each `<tr>` a class such as 'row'

Comment: An example with the amended html can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/fLgbn8hc/ it just alerts the form name on click, but just swap that to submit

Comment: i have accepted this answer.thanks so much. i used your approach